# Why aren't we voting more?

Tags: discussion, voting

It's been noted by some other Android users that people on this site really don't vote often. Voting **increases engagement and helps us sort out good/bad content**. Why aren't people voting and how can we encourage additional voting?

Full disclosure: I haven't used this site very much and I thus haven't voted or done much *yet* but I'm very active else where. Perhaps too many users are drive-bys, but I'd like to see that changed.

Comment: Relevant (semi-)recent chat discussion http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/3826848#3826848 with comparison of our vote numbers to other sites

Comment: Additionally other things like moderating (reviewing, editing posts) is currently not enough on this site.

Comment: Ha so this was an issues in 2012 too?! I guess an Android site will always have this issue.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From what I've seen this site gets more than its fair share of drive-by readers. So, without even a modicum of reputation points they're not doing any voting.

I've not been as active as I would like (for other reasons) but when I am active I try to use up my votes every day. There's often not enough things to vote on, though.