# About 15% of my questions get automatically removed by Roomba (deletion script) because they have score=0 and no answer: Roomba needs to chill

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions

I looked at the list of my removed questions and see that ~15% of my questions (~30 out of my ~210 questions) get automatically removed by Roomba (deletion script) because they have score=0 and no answer. When I look at the questions posted by anyone, a large portion of them also  have score=0 and [no answer](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2669/12202) (I estimate it's is >15%), which means they'll also end up being removed by Roomba.

Since getting more votes seem [difficult](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/q/894/12202), could we relax the rules of Roomba for https://android.stackexchange.com?

Comment: Why? If it wasn't scoring and wasn't answered, might as well post the same question again if you still want to know the answer. Hopefully a better one, so it will attract upvotes and answers. Which will result in the question not being removed again.

Comment: Roomba helps keeping the quality of a site up. Questions nobody cared enough about are cleaned up, so the more interesting questions are easier to find and thus to answer. Everyone wins.

Comment: @Mast "Questions nobody cared enough about are cleaned up" the OP cared enough since they took the time to post the question. It's highly likely other people have the same question. Also, that creates dead links. Lastly, there are very few votes in this site. If someone only cares about upvoted questions, they can add this in the search criteria.

Comment: I didn't invent the system Franck, but it works. Please don't break it.

Comment: @Mast No intent to break it, just improving it. 15% of questions being removed shows it's not working perfectly.

Comment: No, it does work perfectly. Apparently the site does not have the userbase to sustain more questions. The solution is simple: downvote bad questions so they'll be Roomba'd even faster, upvote good questions so they won't be removed.

Comment: @Mast Look at https://android.stackexchange.com/questions: most questions have 0 votes. If we can't fix the users, fix the system.

Comment: No. Your suggestion breaks the system further. If userparticipation is so low that a couple of votes are the problem adjusting the system for an ill community is counterproductive.

Comment: @Mast it means the system isn't well designed for communities with low user participation. [Decrease the required view count to prevent Roomba deletion when score = 0 on smaller sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/355097/178179)

Answer (score 0):

If your questions are being deleted by Roomba is very likely that they are not getting attention from the people who are able to answer them. Follow the guidance from [How do I get attention for one of my own questions without a good answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7046/289691)

By the other hand, it might be possible that

- they can't be answered because nobody knows the answer
- noboby with the privilege to upvote has the same question/problem (upvote to say me too / +1).

---

I have being looking at the things that can be customized by site in Meta Stack Exchange.

The Tour, Help Center homepage and some articles, some close reasons might be customized by the community moderators.

The site theme and Ask Question page might be customized by following the process specified in the correspoding posts in Meta Stack Exchange. Briefly they require a [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) in the respective per-site meta and that a community moderator adds [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review).

Other things might be customized per site, specially those that might require developer time, should made a strong case regarding how that change will impact positively to a large user base. Things like handling rule exceptions per-site it's very likely that might require to be of interest of many small sites, specially those that are not getting traction on Meta Stack Exchange. Yes, getting more upvotes than the average on Meta Stack Exchange posts is not enough to say that a proposal got the required traction and even get good traction there might be other factors that could make that proposal be converterted into a [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) + [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review).

Most feature requests related to the automatic deletion of questions by Roomba doesn't have [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) or have [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined). Here are some examples:

- [Modify the 'has 1 or 0 comments' requirement for 'RemoveAbandonedQuestions' script](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/322197/289691)
- [Request: Don't delete duplicate questions with unique titles and please think twice before downvoting them](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/331417/289691)

You might find more effective spending more time on getting attention to your questions and on fostering a sense of community amongst users of the Stack Exchange sites especially on those with low moderation activity done by the community members, i.e. by helping new users to learn the ropes of small sites, motivate them to participate rather than just "post and run".

More participation very likely will help increase the user base allowed to comment and upvote, thus, very likely that will help that less good questions be deleted automatically by Roomba for being abandoned.

Related

- [What should happen to old unanswered questions where the OP didn't even care to check?](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1010/71386)
- [Should we really have RemoveDeadQuestions on smaller sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/198710/289691)
- [What site-specific configuration settings are possible, and how have they been implemented by the various communities?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/249719/289691)
- [Can we have a guaranteed pipeline for responses from Stack Exchange?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/263662/289691)